# Compute the floor of $(\sqrt{3}+ 1)^5$, or of $(x+ 1)^n$ with $x$ irrational

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, combinatorics, ceiling-and-floor-functions

> How to find $\lfloor(x+ 1)^n\rfloor$ where $x \in\Bbb R - \Bbb Q$ and $n \in \Bbb Z_+$ without using a calculating or calculating the series by hand.
>
> For example, what is $\lfloor(\sqrt{3}+ 1)^5\rfloor$ ?

I thought I would use Bernoulli's inequality, $ 1+ 5\sqrt{3} \le(\sqrt{3}+ 1)^5$, but it is too weak to give a correct answer.

I also tried, $2 < \sqrt{3} + 1 < 3 \implies 32 < (\sqrt{3} + 1)^5 < 243$ but this is also too weak.

I can use $\lfloor x \rfloor = x - \{ x \}$ where $\{x\}$ is fractional part function. Here I need to find $\{x\}$. I don't have any idea to do that either.

Comment: Do you want some kind of formula for the general case?

Comment: @EugenCovaci Some algorithim or trick is also be fine with me. I just want to know how to do these type of questions.

Comment: Are you specifically interested in quadratics?  Since the other root of the quadratic equation $x^2-2x-2$ has norm less than $1$ the linear recursion is helpful.  This trick will not work for, say $\pi +1$.

Comment: @lulu I would like to know a general way to do this, nevertheless I interested in knowing how linear recursion is helpful when norm is less than 1.

Comment: Well, the quadratic suggests that we look at the Fibonacci-like recursion $a_n=2a_{n-1}+2a_{n-2}$.  In general the solutions to that will have the form $A(1+\sqrt 3)^n+B(1-\sqrt 3)^n$ depending on the initial conditions.  If we want $A,B=1$, say, then we require $a_0=2,a_1=2$.  It follows that $a_5=152 = (1+\sqrt 3)^5+(1-\sqrt 3)^5$.  Thus $(1+\sqrt 3 )^5=152 -(1-\sqrt 3)^5$ so your solution is clear.

Comment: Again, this is a trick that only works with the so-called [Perron Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron_number).  That is, algebraic numbers with norm exceeding $1$ but for which all the conjugates have norm less than $1$.

Comment: @lulu One thing, is for all irrational of form $\sqrt{n}$ where $n$ is prime, we will have a recursion of form $a_n = \alpha a_{n-1} + \beta a_{n-2}$ where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the second and third coefficents of the polynomial $(x-(1+ \sqrt{n})) (x-(1 -\sqrt{n}))$

Comment: Not following.  For, say, $1+\sqrt 5$ the simple trick won't help you because $|1-\sqrt 5| \approx 1.236 >1$.

Comment: @lulu Sorry lulu I did not see the second comment of yours.

Comment: 123: I fail to see how the answer you accepted (rather fast, if I may add) solves your question. Would you like to explain?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

First consider $(\sqrt {3}+1)^5=a + b \sqrt{3}$ . Now consider $(\sqrt {3}+1)^5-(\sqrt {3}-1)^5=2a , (\sqrt {3}+1)^5+(\sqrt {3}-1)^5=2b\sqrt {3} $ . I think you know why this is true. Now $\lfloor(\sqrt {3}+1)^5\rfloor=\lfloor a+b\sqrt {3}\rfloor $

Comment: Why did $\lfloor(\sqrt {3}+1)^5\rfloor=\lfloor a+b\sqrt {3}\rfloor=a+b$  ?

Comment: Is $b \in [0, 1]$ and $a \in \Bbb R$ ?

Comment: Sorry i was wrong. Youll have to do a calculation of $b\sqrt {3}$ and then get the floor.

Comment: Actually, if $$(\sqrt {3}+1)^5=a+b\sqrt {3}$$ then $$(\sqrt {3}+1)^5+(\sqrt {3}-1)^5=2b\sqrt3\qquad(\sqrt {3}+1)^5-(\sqrt {3}-1)^5=2a$$ not what you wrote. After that, I fail to understand how your remark that $$\lfloor(\sqrt {3}+1)^5\rfloor=\lfloor a+b\sqrt {3}\rfloor$$ would lead to a solution. But the OP seems to be able to use this to reach a solution...

Comment: "Youll have to do a calculation of $b\sqrt3$ and then get the floor" Fortunately for the method, one would not.

Comment: I think you should correct your answer.

Answer (score 5):

You have chosen a very special example.  $1+\sqrt 3$ is a [Perron number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron_number) in that its absolute value exceeds $1$, clearly, but the absolute value of its conjugate, $1-\sqrt 3$, is less than $1$.

To work with this example, start with the minimal polynomial $x^2-2x-2$.  That leads us to consider the Fibonacci-like recursion $$a_{n+2}=2a_{n+1}+2a_n$$  Of course such a recursion will always have solutions of the form $a_n=A(1+\sqrt 3)^n+B(1-\sqrt 3)^n$ for suitable constants $A,B$.  For our purposes we want $A=B=1$ so we get the initial conditions $a_0=2=a_1$.

We use the recursion to compute $a_5=152$.  This means that $$(1+\sqrt 3)^5=152-(1-\sqrt 3)^5$$  thus $$\boxed {\lfloor (1+\sqrt 3)^5\rfloor =a_5=152}\quad \& \quad  \boxed {\{(1+\sqrt 3)^5\}=-(1-\sqrt 3)^5}$$

Of course, this holds for all odd exponents.  For even exponents you get $$\lfloor (1+\sqrt 3)^{2n}\rfloor = a_{2n}-1\quad \& \quad \{(1+\sqrt 3)^{2n}\}=1-(1-\sqrt 3)^{2n}$$

Note:  this trick will only work with Perron Numbers.